# iterating of properties goes into infinite loop

Tags: javascript

I written a script to iterate over the properties of an object using Object.keys() method. But when I ran, it goes into infinite loop.

```
var employee = {
  "firstName" : "Krishna",
  "lastName" : "Majety",
  "age" : 29,
  "address" : {
    "city" : "Bangalore",
    "area" : "Marthalli"
  }
}


function printProperties(object, objectName, tab){
  var props = Object.keys(object);

  for(i = 0; i < props.length; i++){
    property = props[i];

    if(object[property] instanceof Object){
      printProperties(object[property], objectName+"."+property, "  " + tab);
    }else{
       console.log(tab + objectName + "." + property + " => " + object[property]); 
    }
  }
}

printProperties(employee, "employee", "")
```

It would be great, if any one explain the reason of this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for the help...:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop iterator and property variables are globally scoped, so a nested object will reset them. The fix is to scope with `let` or `var`, or use an array method like `forEach` and skip the iterator entirely.

```
for (let i = 0; ...
  let property = props[i];
```